# Powers of linear functions span the space of polynomial functions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P_n$ be the space of polynomials in $n$ variables over a field of characteristic 0. 
I'm very sure that the space spanned by powers of linear functions is the whole space $P_n$.
Anyone can come up with a proof, or indicate a reference for it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the field/ring? This is certainly not true if $n$ is a prime and the field is of characteristic $n$. Nor is it true over the integers, even if $n=2$: there's no way to get $xy$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the degree, not $n$. Anyway, the statement is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I ask for the field of charactertic 0

Comment: If $n=2$, homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ are generated by $(x+iy)^d$, $i=0,\ldots,d$ (Vandermonde determinant $\ne0$). I think a similar proof can be elaborated for any $n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, actually, the space of homogeneous degree $d$ polynomials in $(n+1)$ variable is generated by 
$$(x_0+i_1x_1+\ldots+i_nx_n)^d,\quad 0\le i_1,\ldots,i_n\le d.$$
For proof, write it as a binomial
$$[(x_0+i_1x_1+\ldots+i_{n-1}x_{n-1})+i_nx_n]^d$$
and, using Vandermonde, get all products $(x_0+i_1x_1+\ldots+i_{n-1}x_{n-1})^px_n^q$, $p+q=d$. Then, use induction.